# If $f$ is a bounded measurable function $\Longrightarrow$ there is a sequence of step functions such that $s_n \longrightarrow f \; a.e$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

If $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded measurable function $\Longrightarrow$ there is a sequence of **step functions** $\displaystyle s_n=\sum_{j=1}^{p} c_j \cdot \chi _{I_j}$ such that $s_n \longrightarrow  f \; a.e$ ?

$\chi _{I_j}$: characteristic function

$I_j$: disjoint intervals with $\bigcup_{j=1}^{p} I_j=[0,1]$

$c_j$: real numbers

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Note to users under 10k: there are already 3 deleted answers that show the result for simple functions. The question asks for step functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f$ is integrable. The step functions are dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ (corollary 18 [here](http://math.la.asu.edu/~quigg/teach/courses/473/2009/lectures/11integral.pdf)). A fortiori in $L^1([0,1])$. So there exists a sequence $(s_n)$ of step functions converging to $f$ in $L^1$. Finally, there exists a subsequence of the latter converging a.e. pointwise to $f$. As it is the case in general for convergent sequences in an $L^p$ space.

Comment: Ah yes, because continuous functions are dense. I should have thought of this.